# llvm pass: How to insert a variable using existing variable value

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I defined `int a = 5`; in the source code, and I transform the source to LLVM IR:

```
%a = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 5, i32* %a, align 4
```

I want to insert `int b = a;` by writing a pass. I compile `int a=5; int b=a` into LLVM IR, it load "a" first, then store it. I also checked the doxygen, in which the LoadInst is `LoadInst (Value *Ptr, const Twine &NameStr, Instruction *InsertBefore)` Still, I don't know how to get the `Value` of "a".

How to get a variable value?

Answer (score 3):

In LLVM IR the sequence

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
```

without any optimization, is translated as

```
%a = alloca i32, align 4
%b = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 5, i32* %a, align 4
%0 = load i32* %a, align 4
store i32 %0, i32* %b, align 4
```

This corresponds to two `AllocaInst`s, two `StoreInst`s and a `LoadInst` as follows

<sub>*warning: untested/uncompiled pseudocode ahead*</sub>

```
ConstantInt* const_int_5 = ConstantInt::get(llvmContext, APInt(32, StringRef("5"), 10));

AllocaInst* a_alloc = new AllocaInst(IntegerType::get(llvmContext, 32), "a");
AllocaInst* b_alloc = new AllocaInst(IntegerType::get(llvmContext, 32), "b");
StoreInst* store_5 = new StoreInst(const_int_5, a_alloc, false);
LoadInst* load_from_a = new LoadInst(a_alloc, "", false);
StoreInst* store_b = new StoreInst(load_from_a, b_alloc, false);
```

You're probably being confused since **the instruction is the value** in LLVM API thanks to a well-designed inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you misunderstand what I really mean. I can get a similar answer using `llc -march`. How should I do to transform the IR code in my question to the IR code in your answer? Due to the alloca and store inst has been existed in the IR code, what should I do to get "a_alloca"?

Comment: I don't understand the English of your sentence. Do you want to change the name of the "a" variable to "a_alloca"? If so, change the `const Twine &Name=""` parameter of the `AllocaInst` constructor

Comment: I think the OP just wants to add a second local variable b (with new AllocaInst) in his pass and initialize it with the value from the _already present_ local variable 'a'. To do this, he needs to tell the LoadInst to access local variable 'a'.  The question was how to do this.